# Can I Use a Vanilla Torchlight 2 Character With a Modded TL2?

Tags: mods, torchlight-2

So I have a higher level Berserker and wanted to create a mod myself to change some minor things. The problem is as soon as I load the mod I don't have access to my vanilla character. Can I somehow play the same character across vanilla/modded-Torchlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonah Bishop's answer is incorrect. There is no flagging, but:

> It is possible to copy your saves over from an un-modded state to enable mod access, but be advised that we cannot guarantee that it will work flawlessly, particularly if you take a character from a modded state and bring it back into an un-modded mode of gameplay.

Source: https://support.runicgames.com/kb/articles/55-game-saves-inaccessible-when-playing-with-mods

Comment: In spite of their warning, I believe it will work most of the time. The nature of the mod defines if it will work. It can be assumed that transferring the save of an unmodded Berzerker, for example, into a modded game where the class has been replaced or removed would be problematic. It should be safe with mods only adding content.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed use vanilla characters in mod mode, but once they've been flagged as using mods, they can't go back to vanilla-land (to my knowledge).

Simply:

1. Browse to your Torchlight folder, and go into the *save* folder.
2. Copy all of the files in this folder (or just the ones for your specific character, if you just want to move one over).
3. Change into the *modsave* folder (it's a sibling to the *save* folder).
4. Paste the files you copied into this location.

Now all your vanilla characters should appear when you start the game using mods.

Comment: brilliant, thanks. and thats ok if I cant move it back to vanilla mode.